# QT setMouseTracking(true) has no effect at all

Tags: c++, qt

so here is my code, I am trying to capture mouse input which does not work unless I hold down my left key on my mouse. Keyboard input works perfectly fine.

```
  QWidget *window = new QWidget();
  QHBoxLayout *hl = new QHBoxLayout();
  QVBoxLayout *vl = new QVBoxLayout();
  main = new input_browser_main();
  main->setFixedWidth(640);
  main->setFixedHeight(480);

  hl->addWidget(vncmain);
  vl->addLayout(hl);
  QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget();
  centralWidget->setLayout (layout);
  centralWidget->setFixedHeight(100);
  vl->addWidget(centralWidget);
  window->setLayout(vl);

  this->setCentralWidget(window);
}
```

For some reason the mouse movement is not captured? I am calling setMouseTracking but I receive no data. I am relatively new to QT and C++ and am making this application in response to a UI demanded by a client.. So what I am trying to achieve is to get the mouse x,y for only inside the Widget.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable mouse tracking for the widgets the mouse is actually on. It seems you have child widgets. Those child widgets need to have mouse tracking enabled so that they propagate the mouse move events to their parent.

You can just call `setMouseTracking(true);` once. You don't need to enable/disable mouse tracking when the mouse enters/leaves. That means you don't need `enterEvent()` and `leaveEvent()` handlers.